# ssh connection sometimes prints "No route to host", other times it connects normally

Tags: ssh, routes, remote-access, host, openssh

I have two laptops :
- The first with Debian squeeze , is connected via ethernet and has the ip address 192.168.0.2
- The second with Ubuntu 12.10 is connected via wlan and has the ip address 192.168.0.9

the problem is:
- If I try to use ssh from the first to the second I get this result :

```
laptop1@192.168.0.2:~$ ssh laptop2@192.168.0.9
"ssh : connect to host 192.168.0.9 port 22: No route to host "
```

- If I try to use ssh from the second to the first , it connects successfully to the first.

  ```
  laptop2@192.168.0.9:~$ ssh laptop1@192.168.0.1
  ```
- And now if I try again to connect from the first to the second , it connects successfully to the second

  ```
  laptop1@192.168.0.2:~$ ssh laptop2@192.168.0.9
  ```

but after a few minutes if I try to use ssh from the first to the second , I still get this result :

```
"ssh : connect to host 192.168.0.9 port 22: No route to host ".
```

Typing the command arp  on laptop1 I noticed that I cannot connect from the laptop1 to the laptop2 when disappears the ip address of laptop2.

```
laptop1@192.168.0.2:~$ sudo arp

Address       HWtype   HWAddress        Flags  Mask  Iface
192.168.0.1   ether   00:1b:2f:3f:b5:a2   C           eth0
192.168.0.9   ether   e4:d5:3d:03:3b:ed   C           eth0
```

after few minutes...

```
laptop1@192.168.0.2:~$ sudo arp

Address       HWtype   HWAddress        Flags  Mask  Iface
192.168.0.1   ether   00:1b:2f:3f:b5:a2   C           eth0
```

**someone understands why this happens? and how can I fix it?**

I post some more information of my two laptops:

- for the laptop1:

  ```
  laptop1@192.168.0.2:~$ sudo ifconfig
  eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:cf:30:08:e0:82  
    inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
    inet6 addr: fe80::22cf:30ff:fe08:e082/64 Scope:Link
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:29290 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:28325 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
    RX bytes:20301572 (19.3 MiB)  TX bytes:11035023 (10.5 MiB)
    Interrupt:30 

  lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
    inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
    inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
    UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
    RX packets:1440 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:1440 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
    RX bytes:166450 (162.5 KiB)  TX bytes:166450 (162.5 KiB)

  wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:f0:6d:76:79:93  
    inet6 addr: fe80::76f0:6dff:fe76:7993/64 Scope:Link
    UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:42 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:81 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
    RX bytes:10888 (10.6 KiB)  TX bytes:16236 (15.8 KiB)



  laptop1@192.168.0.2:~$ sudo route -n
  Kernel IP routing table
  Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
  192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
  169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
  0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
  ```
- for the laptop2:

  ```
  laptop2@192.168.0.9:~$ sudo ifconfig
  eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:7d:7b:1e:47:8b  
    UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
    RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

  lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
    inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
    inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
    UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
    RX packets:124 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:124 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
    RX bytes:10373 (10.3 KB)  TX bytes:10373 (10.3 KB)

  wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e4:d5:3d:03:3b:ed  
    inet addr:192.168.0.9  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
    inet6 addr: fe80::e6d5:3dff:fe03:3bed/64 Scope:Link
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:1434 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:1329 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
    RX bytes:1274245 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:188474 (188.4 KB)



  laptop2@192.168.0.9:~$ sudo route -n
  Kernel IP routing table
  Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
  0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
  169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
  192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
  ```